# I want to add new button or text in Addtocart screen in POS Odoo 10

Tags: odoo-10

I'm trying to implement the loyal program in odoo 10.
this functionality works in odoo 8 as same trying to develop in 10 
Tried with this below code

I have 3 model classs . im getting the all data from model.load_models
though im not getting the button in pos screen under addto cart screen

**loyal.xml**

```
<templates id="template" xml:space="preserve">

 <t t-name="LoyaltyPoints">
    <div class='loyalty-points'>
        <div class='loyalty-points-title'>Points</div>
        <t t-if='points_won'>
            <div class="loyalty-points-won">
                <span class='value'>+<t t-esc='widget.format_pr(points_won,1)'/></span>  
            </div>
        </t>
        <t t-if='points_spent'>
            <div class="loyalty-points-spent">
                <span class='value'>-<t t-esc='widget.format_pr(points_spent,1)'/></span> 
            </div>
        </t>
        <div class='loyalty-points-total'>
            <span class='value'><t t-esc='widget.format_pr(points_total,1)' /></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>    

<t t-name="LoyaltyButton">
    <div class='control-button'>
        <i class='fa fa-tag' /> Rewards
    </div>
</t>
</templates>
```

**loyal.js**

```
odoo.define('pos_loyalty_program.pos_loyalty_program', function (require) {
"use strict";

var models = require('point_of_sale.models');
var screens = require('point_of_sale.screens');
var core = require('web.core');
var utils = require('web.utils');
var gui     = require('point_of_sale.gui');
var _t      = core._t;

var round_pr = utils.round_precision;
var QWeb     = core.qweb;


models.load_fields('res.partner','loyalty_points');
models.load_models([
                {
                    model: 'loyal.program',
                    condition: function(self){ return !!self.config; },
                    fields: ['name'],
                    domain: function(self){ 
                    return [['id','=',self.config.related_loyal_program_id[0]]]; },
                    loaded: function(self,loyalties){ 
                        self.loyalty = loyalties[0]; 
                    },
                   {
                    model: 'loyal.rule',}
                     {
                    model: 'loyal.award',}
                },
 ],{'after': 'product.product'});

var LoyaltyButton = screens.ActionButtonWidget.extend({
template: 'LoyaltyButton',
button_click: function(){
    var order  = this.pos.get_order();
    var client = order.get_client(); 
    if (!client) {
          this.gui.show_screen('clientlist');
        return;
    }

    var rewards = order.get_available_rewards();
    if (rewards.length === 0) {
        this.gui.show_popup('alert',{
            'title': 'No Rewards Available',
            'body':  'There are no rewards available for this customer as part of the loyalty program',
        });
        return;
    } else if (rewards.length === 1 && this.pos.loyalty.rewards.length === 1) {
        order.apply_reward(rewards[0]);
        return;
    } else { 
        var list = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < rewards.length; i++) {
            list.push({
                label: rewards[i].name,
                item:  rewards[i],
            });
        }
        this.gui.show_popup('selection',{
            'title': 'Please select a reward',
            'list': list,
            'confirm': function(reward){
                order.apply_reward(reward);
            },
        });
    }
},
 });

screens.define_action_button({
'name': 'loyalty',
'widget': LoyaltyButton,
'condition': function(){
    return this.pos.loyalty && this.pos.loyalty.rewards.length;
},
});
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve this .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Odoo 10 add button to POS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997252/odoo-10-add-button-to-pos)

Answer (score 0):

Just build the widget. For example something like this:

```
module.PosWidget.include({

    build_widgets: function(){
      var self = this;
      this._super();

      // --------  Button screen and his selector ---------
      this.button_screen = new module.LoyaltyButton(this,{});
      this.button_screen.appendTo(this.$('.screens'));
      this.screen_selector.add_screen('loyalty',this.button_screen);
    }
```